# Bluetooth develop:sometimes the bluetoothadapter cannot find the device

Tags: android

I'm working at BLE develop and there is my problem.

Sometimes my bluetoothadapter cannot find the device when I used method bluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(callback).

And when adapter cannot found device,I just restart bluetoothadapter(meant:turn off the bluetoothadapter then turn on).

And then the callback will return the device instead null.

I have search much about BLE develop ,but it seems like nobody found this problem.

This is my callback:

```
private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback = new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi,byte[] scanRecord) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                synchronized (m_LeDevices) {
                    if (m_device_mac != null && m_device_mac.equals(device.getAddress().replace(":", ""))) {
                        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                forwardToMain();
                            }
                        }, DELAY_FORWARD_TIME);                         
                    }                       
                }
            }
        });
    }

};
```

Comment: are you working on iBeacons???

Comment: No，I'm working on Eclipse

Comment: What exactly you are trying to build and what exactly you want...be clear??/

Comment: I want make sure the bluetoothadapter can return the device when I used bluetoothadapter.startLeScan(callback).Sometimes , it's just not work...But  when I restarted bluetoothadapter,it worked..I want skip this step,don't need restart the bluetooth-switch.

Comment: Omg,is somebody can help me ?
I guess the problem was caused by I have not notify the app to release adapter for scan .But I have tried this, it does't work.                                  Is the adapter can only get one instance?